# ¿Cómo convertir un tag de BeautifulSoup a JSON?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

Tengo un elemento de tipo, `bs4.element.Tag` , producto de un web scraping, normalmente hago: `json.loads(soup.find('script',type='application/ld+json').text)`, pero en esta página solo aparece en:`<script> </script>` 
entonces tuve que hacer: `scripts = soup.find_all('script')` hasta llegar al que me interesa: `script = scripts[18]`.

La variable en cuestión es `script`.
Mi problema es que quiero acceder a sus atributos, por ejemplo `script['goodsInfo']`, obviamente al ser un elemento tipo `bs4.element.Tag`, intente hacer: `script.attrs` y me devuelve `{}`.
Entonces intente convertirlo al tipo `json`: `json.loads(str(script))` y me arroja la *excepción:* *'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'*

Este es mi código:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url_aux = 'https://www.shein.com/Mock-neck-Brush-Stroke-Print-Bodycon-Dress-p-941649-cat-1727.html?scici=navbar_2~~tab01navbar04~~4~~real_1727~~~~0~~0'

response = requests.get(url_aux)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

scripts = soup.find_all('script')
script = scripts[18]

print(json.loads(str(script)))
#output: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

print(type(script))
#output: bs4.element.Tag

print(str(json.loads(str(script))))
```

Answer (score 1):

La variable script contiene un element.Tag, no el contenido de ese Tag.

Simplemente tienes que acceder al contenido de ese Tag con .text, es decir:

```
json.loads(str(script.text))
```